# como retornar duas arrays distintas usando union all

Tags: php, mysql

```
        $stmt = $this->db->query("
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, status as tipo FROM tabela1 WHERE status=1 GROUP BY SEXO UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, status as tipo FROM tabela2 WHERE status=1 GROUP BY FAIXA_ETARIA
");
    $total = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

como retornar uma array assim (duas arrays com todos os valores referentes ao select):

```
$total['sexo'] = "todos os valores referentes a este select dentro desta array"

$total['FAIXA_ETARIA'] = "todos os valores referentes a este select dentro desta array"
```

existe um modo de se fazer isso sem fazer 2 querys separadas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```html
$stmt = $this->db->query("
    select count(*) as total
       from tabela1 where status=1
    union all
    select count(*) as total
       from tabela2 where status=1
");

$total = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sexo = $total[0];

echo 'Sexo: '.$sexo['total'].'<br>';

$faixa_etaria = $total[1];

echo 'Faixa etária: '.$faixa_etaria['total'];
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO:** sempre tente manter seus códigos com no máximo 80 caracteres por linha.